# Error while installing rails (no write permissions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, rubygems, rbenv

I was in the middle of installing Rails (gem install rails) on my Mac when I got the following error:

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the Users/[myusername]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin directory.
```

I was installing via rbenv. I'd installed ruby-2.0.something and the ruby-1.9.3-p428.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `sudo gem install rails` before typing you command then it will ask for your root password to confirm this action

sudo = super user do , when ever you face this problem (no write permissions) it will be solved by using `sudo`